# Angular 6 + Bootstrap 4 Select all and Deselect all Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, angular6

I'm having an issue trying to get Bootstrap 4 Checkboxes working with a select all and deselect all option in angular 6+. I can get it to work when I use the original code here:
http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/04/select-all-deselect-all-checkbox.html
But the issue is Bootstrap uses a different event to click their checkboxes. Does anyone have a solution for this?

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" (change)="selectAll()">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        Select All
      </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let n of names">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{n.name}}" [(ngModel)]="selectedNames" (change)="checkIfAllSelected()">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        {{n.name}}
      </label>
</div>
```

And the TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkbox',
  templateUrl: './checkbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkbox.component.scss']
})
export class CheckboxComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Checkbox';
  names: any;
  selectedAll: any;
  constructor() {
    this.title = "Select all/Deselect all checkbox - Angular 2";
    this.names = [
      { name: 'Prashobh', selected: false },
      { name: 'Abraham', selected: false },
      { name: 'Anil', selected: false },
      { name: 'Sam', selected: false },
      { name: 'Natasha', selected: false },
      { name: 'Marry', selected: false },
      { name: 'Zian', selected: false },
      { name: 'karan', selected: false },
    ]

  }
  selectAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.names.length; i++) {
      this.names[i].selected = this.selectedAll;
    }
  }
  checkIfAllSelected() {
    this.selectedAll = this.names.every(function(item:any) {
        return item.selected == true;
      })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this should do it

Here is a plnkr: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/ypGmwE32Xn1bgbqd?preview

HTML:

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" (change)="selectAll()" [checked]="selectedAll">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        Select All
      </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let n of names">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{n.name}}" [(ngModel)]="n.selected" (change)="checkIfAllSelected()">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        {{n.name}}
      </label>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkbox',
  templateUrl: './checkbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkbox.component.scss']
})
export class CheckboxComponent implements OnInit {


    title = 'Checkbox';
  names: any;
  selectedAll: any;
  selectedNames: any;
    constructor() {
          this.title = "Select all/Deselect all checkbox - Angular 2";
    this.names = [
      { name: 'Prashobh', selected: false },
      { name: 'Abraham', selected: false },
      { name: 'Anil', selected: false },
      { name: 'Sam', selected: false },
      { name: 'Natasha', selected: false },
      { name: 'Marry', selected: false },
      { name: 'Zian', selected: false },
      { name: 'karan', selected: false },
    ]
    }
    selectAll() {
        this.selectedAll = !this.selectedAll;

        for (var i = 0; i < this.names.length; i++) {
            this.names[i].selected = this.selectedAll;
        } 
  }
  checkIfAllSelected() {
      var totalSelected =  0;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.names.length; i++) {
            if(this.names[i].selected) totalSelected++;
        } 
    this.selectedAll = totalSelected === this.names.length;

  return true;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure bootstrap has any special logic for event binding in checkbox. I suppose that is missing in your code. for binding see following snippet:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="form-check" formArrayName="unitArr">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [checked]="checkAllSelected()" 
         (click)="selectAll($event.target.checked)" id="select-all">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="select-all">
                            Select All
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let n of names; let i = index;" >
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{n.name}}" [(ngModel)]="selectedNames" (change)="checkIfAllSelected()" [attr.id]="'check' + i">
                        <label class="form-check-label" [attr.for]="'check' + i">
                            {{n.name}}
                        </label>
                    </div>
</form>

checkAllSelected() {
  return this.form.controls.unitArr.controls.every(x => x.value == true)
}

selectAll(isChecked) {
  if isChecked 
     this.form.controls.unitArr.controls.map(x => x.patchValue(true))
  else
     this.form.controls.unitArr.controls.map(x => x.patchValue(false))
}
```

the "id" of input has to be mapped to "label" with "for". Not sure if you have any special requirement, but this is very basic HTML concept. Please give it a try, and see if your problem is solved.

Edit : Please note, I am not familiar with Angular6 concepts, however above code does work with Angular 2. You may check if any of the above points help you anyhow. All the best!

Comment: So this now allows the second box to select all instead of the 1st, and you cannot select the others. Any ideas?

Comment: This does not answer his question. Although you are correct about needing the for reference IF he wants the text to also check the box nothing in question asks for this.

Comment: @racamp101 please read again what i mentioned above "I am not sure bootstrap has any special logic for event binding in checkbox"!!!. And read Robert's above comment, the logic does help him in solving as this basic handling was missing in his code. Humble suggestion, please be considerate about questioner concerns before downvoting!