# How to disable all check box if user selected none? The checkbox values in drop down

Tags: angular, angular-material

The checkbox values in dropdown, if user selected none of the above it clear all the values .

for example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-multi-c6vtux?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: do u want to clear/uncheck all the checkbox? or want to disable the checkbox?

Comment: i want to clear ,if user selected none of these,

Comment: Here you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51776897/angular-6-bootstrap-4-select-all-and-deselect-all-checkboxes/51793079